# Bootstrap remove columns for print

Tags: css, flask, bootstrap-4

I have a page that has two columns

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 "></div>
        <div class="d-print-none col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I try to print the page the right hand column disappears (as instructed) but the left hand column does not resize and to the effect is that the right column is essentially still there.

How do I hide the right column and get the left one to fill the page for printing?

--Update--

I have changed my code to the following

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="d-print-none">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 ">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>
            <div class="d-print-none col-md-4"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-none d-print-block">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works when the

> {% block content %}{% endblock %}

is not in the code (this is Python Flask). But when it is there I get an error saying

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateAssertionError: block 'content' defined
>   twice

Obviously I can see that the block content is indeed there twice, however I need it to be as on is for the print content the other is for screen content.

Answer (score 0):

Responsive utilities in **Print classes**

`visible-print-block` only while print the page.

Bootstrap **[responsive-utilities-print](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/#responsive-utilities-print)**

**[Demo](https://codepen.io/uidesigner/pen/zeVPaB)**

Comment: How do I get that to work? I have <div class="hidden-print col-md-4"> but it still shows in print.

Comment: @coolblue2000 sounds like you need to stop mixing BS v3 and v4 syntax … `hidden-print` is v3, v4 uses `d-print-none`

Comment: I have just realised that. I only put it in because this answer suggested too... However I have used 2 divs. One that shows in print with one single 12 column div and the other that shows on screen with an 8 column and a 4 column div. This sort of works but I now get an error "TemplateAssertionError: block 'content' defined twice" the problem is that the block content needs to be in both....